# No method found while using com.jfrog.artifactory plugin

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

I am new to gradle please pardon my ignorance. Have a basic gradle project.
I get the following error when I run ./gradlew tasks

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '<path>/build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
> No signature of method: build_204u1riu5haork78eb2ib9dc1t$_run_closure2.id() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.jfrog.artifactory]
  Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object), find(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Following is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url '<URL>'
            credentials {
                username = "<USERNAME>"
                password = "<PASSWORD>"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.9')
    }
}

plugins {
   id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "3.0.1"   //<=== LINE 17
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'application'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "<URL>"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
            username = "<USERNAME>"
            password = "<PASSWORD>"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-all'
            username = "<USERNAME>"
            password = "<PASSWORD>"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'

    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.38'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2'
}
```

I am sure it is a very basic issue which is why when I googled around, did not find any solutions. Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction or share a link to any previous related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you are building using Gradle 1.x. The Gradle [plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) was introduced in [Gradle 2.1](https://docs.gradle.org/2.1/release-notes#easier-use-of-community-plugins) and is not supported by older Gradle version.
You have [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) configured to use Gradle 2.2, but you need to make sure you are using the `gradlew` script instead of `gradle`

Comment: If by "gradlew script" you mean gradlew tasks or gradlew clean, then yes I am using those instead of gradle tasks or gradle clean.

Comment: What version do you see when running ./gradlew -version ? do you get the error when using gradlew?

Comment: Gradle 1.12 is what I see. Now, I understand what you mean. What should I be doing to use Gradle 2.x?

Comment: You need to run the gradle wrapper task. This will should install the wrapper into your project. Than make sure the updated version is committed to version control. For more info, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate the help. I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is if you have any module in your project which has lower version gradle tools

e.g my app module had below build tools as dependency in buildscript

 
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'**

but I had another module with below build tools as dependency in buildscript
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'**

In this situation I got below error

> No signature of method: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener$_projectsEvaluated_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.ArtifactoryTask_Decorated) values: [task ':uid:artifactoryPublish']

Then after changing 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' everything worked well.